# Objects in Pinned Object Heap (I do not pin them)

Tags: visual-studio, memory-management, profiling

I see some of my objects in Pinned Object Heap when I profile my net6.0 console application using .NET Object Allocation Tracking tool in Visual Studio 17.6.2

I definitely do not pin them explicitly. Why my object get into the POH? Should I worry?